# NHibernate model mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this database schema (MS SQL 2008):

```
Shops
   ID int (PK)
   Name nvarchar(200)

Suppliers
   ID int (PK)
   ShopID int (FK->Shops.ID)
   Name nvarchar(200)

Contacts
   ID int (PK)
   SupplierID int (FK->Suppliers.ID)
   Phone nvarchar(100)
```

I have these models in my project:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<SupplierContact> SupplierContacts { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierContact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I played around with mapping files to load my `Shop` model but with no luck. The main thing is I do not need a `Supplier` model and I have no idea how mapping should be implemented to load all supplier phones as a child list for `Shop` model.

Any help on how to create mapping is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. `Shop` and `SupplierContact` models will not be altered or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<class name="SupplierContact" table="SupplierContact">
   <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="native" />
   </id>
   ... other properties etc ...
   <many-to-one name="Shop" column="ShopId" class="Shop" />
</class>

<class name="Shop" table="Shop">
   <id name="Id" column="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
   </id>
   ... properties etc ...
   <set name="SupplierContacts" table="SupplierContact">
      <key column="ShopId" />
      <one-to-many class="SupplierContact" />
   </set>
</class>
```

Edit: fixed typo.

Comment: Something is not right here: I get `Shop`s with only one `SupplierContact` ant they both have same ID.

Comment: Can you post up where you are actually working with the class? Sounds as though something else is going on.  Another option is to look at NHProf - it shows all DB transactions going on through NH, and can help shed more light.

Comment: NH complains about `name` attribute in `key` node. I'm using NH 2.1.2 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Ahh yes - oops - my mistake. should be <key column="id" /> - My apologies.

Comment: With <key column="id" /> id does not work - NH tries to select Shop with SupplierContacts where Shops.ID = SupplierContacts.ID. Checked with SQL Profiler

Comment: Related to the missing foreign key i think.  See above.

Comment: Weird results and nothing close to expected :(

Comment: Such as? What are weird results exactly? Maybe post your c# code where you are working with the models.